# Edições BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estou usando um tema bootstrap com imagem de background mas a imagem não muda.
Fui no css, alterei o background de todo jeito e a imagem se mantem mesmo sendo uma url que não existe mais.

Como não tem nada sobre no código html, segue o css:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px; 
}

.image-bg-fluid-height,
.image-bg-fixed-height {
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.image-bg-fluid-height {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.image-bg-fixed-height {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 450px;
}

.img-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
    padding: 75px 0;
}

.section-heading {
    margin: 30px 0;
    font-size: 4em;
}

.section-lead {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.section-paragraph {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    section {
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .section-heading {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto provavelmente deve ser porque seu site está salvo no cache do navegador, atualize a página apertando

> ctrl+f5

Comment: Era exatamente isso!

Comment: Que bom! Se puder diga que a resposta foi útil

Comment: Eu ainda não posso por causa dos meus pontos de reputação, mas vou me lembrar de fazer isso quando tiver.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que exista em algum outro trecho do código um css definindo o background com a imagem em questão e isso está gerando conflito de css, para resolver esse conflito você pode utilizar o atributo `!important` que servirá para priorizar o css definido por você.

```
body{
   background-image: url("imagem.jpg") !important;
}
```

Comment: Isso vai ser muito útil pra um outro problema em outro código que eu tenho. Obrigada.